# UIButton does not have a member named 'target'

Tags: ios, swift

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/) which states to put the following code:

```
if self.revealViewController() != nil {
   menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
   menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
   self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
}
```

I have created a `UIButton` in storyboards and made an outlet to my cade with the variable name `menuButton` but I am getting the errors:

```
UIButton does not have a member named 'target'
UIButton does not have a member named 'action'
```

Any ideas what I should be using instead since those members don't exist?

Comment: Show the declaration of `menuButton`.

Comment: If a tutorial says to do that I'd question the tutorial. Assuming menuButton is a subclass of UIButton, it does not have a target or action property, and that code would never work. Maybe menuButton is a custom class that should have `target` and `action` properties. You need to provide more information.

Comment: "I am following this tutorial" No, you're not. If you were, you wouldn't be having this problem.

Comment: @matt: If you follow the link to the tutorial, you’ll see that it includes exactly that code. Unclear why the author included that, or why *they* thought it would work…

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon I did follow the link and I did the tutorial and it works fine, for the reason I explained in my answer. A UIBarButtonItem is not a UIButton.

Comment: Ah, good point. I hadn’t downloaded the sample project—the tutorial itself doesn’t mention either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep—UIControl (the superclass of UIButton) doesn’t expose those as properties, because there can be more than one of them and they can be associated with distinct events. There’s a method instead, [-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:)

```
menuButton.addTarget(self.revealViewController(), action: "revealToggle:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 2):

You, for some reason, have decided to go against the tutorial and use a UIButton. A UIButton is a UIControl. See the docs for UIControl:
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

As you can see, you call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`.

The reason it doesn't work for you the way the tutorial says is that you didn't follow the tutorial. In the tutorial, this thing is *not* a UIButton - it is a UIBarButtonItem, a very different animal, which *does* have a `target` property and an `action` property.